# Sufficient and necessary conditions for a smooth function to have a Fourier transform with rapid decay

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R) \cap L^1(\mathbb R)$. I want to learn necessary and sufficient conditions for the Fourier transform
$$\hat f (y) := \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \exp(-2 \pi i xy) dx$$
to have rapid decay. Meaning that we have
$$\lim_{|y| \to \infty} y^k \hat f(y) = 0$$
for all $k \in \mathbb N_0$.

Using the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma and the fact
$$\hat{f^{(k)}}(y) = (2 \pi i y)^k \hat f(y)$$
in case $f^{(k)} \in L^1$ we get $\hat f$ has rapid decay if all derivatives of $f$ are in $L^1$. So this condition is **sufficient**. Is it also **necessary**?

Which other sufficient and necessary conditions are there?

Comment: By Fourier inversion, you see that a necessary condition is to have all derivatives of $f$ in $C_0 \cap L^2$. I doubt that you can get all the way to $L^1$.

Comment: I *think* that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ is enough for $\hat{f}$ to be rapidly decaying.